# Unable to Open Xamarian Android App on Mobile

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have develop a basic Xamarian Android App it works fine when using Developer Options on mobile. But when i transfer(copy and paste on mobile) same App to mobile it Didn't open instead showing Blank White screen on Mobile. If mobile screen gets locked and when screen lock open the App closed automatically.

Don't know what to do Because I am beginner to this.

Comment: `it Didn't open instead showing Blank White screen on Mobile.`  Is there any log about this problem?